# atribuir um value a variavel javascript

Tags: php, javascript

O problema é o seguinte o php me retorna vários botoes com um input escondido para identificar o botão.

```
$nome = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menbros ORDER BY id");
while ($row = $nome->fetch_assoc()) {
$nome = $row['identifier'];
$i    = $row['id'];
<input type='hidden' value='".$i."' id='troca'/>
<button type='button' onclick='troca()'>
}
```

eu preciso que a variavel javascript pegue o value do input do botão q foi clicado.

essa forma a baixo me retorna o primeiro input da pagina mas como tenho varios preciso que minha variavel pegue o valor do input acima do botão clicado.
    
    var troca = $("#troca").val();

Comment: Descreva melhor pois está passível a fechamento. Faça um tour para entender melhor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não uses a mesma ID para elementos diferentes, ou seja IDs têm de ser únicas e só pode haver uma por página, sem repetições.

Uma alternativa seria assim:

```
$nome = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menbros ORDER BY id");
while ($row = $nome->fetch_assoc()) {
    $nome = $row['identifier'];
    $i    = $row['id'];
    echo "<button type='button' onclick='troca(this)' value='".$i."'>";
}
```

sem `input` e sem `id`. Assim podes pegar o `value` do botão diretamente...

e no JavaScript:

```
function troca(btn) {
    alert('Botão nr: ' + btn.value);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/occd1upa/